# Django PasswordInput is printing object instead of form field

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to create my own authentication system by making use of Django Auth module. The problem is when I print my form in the template, Username and text field is displaying fine but the password field its displaying object something like this `<django.forms.widgets.PasswordInput object at 0x00000000039E1710>`

Here is my form

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required = True)
    password = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True)
```

And the template goes here.

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="/portal/login">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

Some one help me on this

-Vikram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
password = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True)
```

to

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the answer: After correcting the form like this its displaying fine

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
   username = forms.CharField(required = True)
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

Sorry for the spam

-Vikram